# How to fix SSD Boot Order Acer Aspire E15

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

Hi i just bought an SSD and a HDDCaddy to upgrade my Aspire E15 (E5-521-65BL).
Removed the DVD optical drive and replaced it with it.
Windows recognizes the SSD so I was able to clone my systempartition to the SSD drive.
Now when i rebooted my laptop and went into BIOS to change boot-order, my SSD does not show up ?? I only see Windows Boot Manager and my old HDD.

How to make sure my laptop boots from the new SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is solved!

THe problem with some laptops is that the bios prevents you from booting from your second sata. I installed the new ssd where the old hdd was and vice versa and this way i was able to boot to install to my new ssd!